# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'insertOne')

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-modules

I had this error when I try to add a review using the curl command:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:4444/api/v1/reviews/new -H “Content-Type:application/json” -d ‘{“movieId”:12,”user”:”sara”,”review”:”good”}’
```

**reviews.controller.js**

```
import reviewsDAO from "../dao/reviewsDAO.js";

export default class ReviewsController{

  static async apiPostReview(req, res, next) {
    try {
      const movieId = parseInt(req.body.movieId)
      const review = req.body.review
      const user = req.body.user
      console.log('movieId', movieId)
      const reviewResponse = await reviewsDAO.addReview(
        movieId,
        user,
        review
      )
      res.json({ status: "success" })
    } catch (e) {
      res.status(500).json({ error: e.message })
    }
  }

  static async apiGetReview(req, res, next) {
    try {
      let id = req.params.id || {}
      let review = await reviewsDAO.getReview(id)
      if (!review) {
        res.status(404).json({ error: "Not found" })
        return
      }
      res.json(review)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(`api, ${e}`)
      res.status(500).json({ error: e })
    }
  }

  static async apiUpdateReview(req, res, next) {
    try {
      const reviewId = req.params.id
      const review = req.body.review
      const user = req.body.user

      const reviewResponse = await reviewsDAO.updateReview(
        reviewId,
        user,
        review
      )

      var { error } = reviewResponse
      if (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ error })
      }

      if (reviewResponse.modifiedCount === 0) {
        throw new Error(
          "unable to update review",
        )
      }

      res.json({ status: "success" })
    } catch (e) {
      res.status(500).json({ error: e.message })
    }
  }

  static async apiDeleteReview(req, res, next) {
    try {
      const reviewId = req.params.id
      const reviewResponse = await reviewsDAO.deleteReview(reviewId)
      res.json({ status: "success" })
    } catch (e) {
      res.status(500).json({ error: e.message })
    }
  }

  static async apiGetReviews(req, res, next) {
    try {
      let id = req.params.id || {}
      let reviews = await reviewsDAO.getReviewsByMovieId(id)
      if (!reviews) {
        res.status(404).json({ error: "Not found" })
        return
      }
      res.json(reviews)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(`api, ${e}`)
      res.status(500).json({ error: e })
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried several solutions but I didn't resolve the issue

**reviewsDAO.js**:

```
import mongodb from 'mongodb';
const ObjectID=mongodb.ObjectID;


let reviews;

export default class ReviewsDAO{
    static async injectDB(conn){
        if(reviews){
            return
        }
        try{
            reviews = await conn.db("reviews").collection("reviews");
        } catch(e){
            console.error(`Unable to establish collection handles in userDAO: ${e}..`);
        };
    };

    static async addReview(movieId,user,review){
        try{
            const reviewDoc={
                movieId:movieId,
                user:user,
                review:review
            }
            return await reviews.insertOne(reviewDoc);
        }catch(e){
            console.error(`Unable to post review: ${e}`);
            return{error:e};
        };
    };

    static async getReview(reviewId){
        try{
            return await reviews.findOne({_id:ObjectID(reviewId)})
        }catch(e){
            console.error(`Unable to get review: ${e}`);
            return{error:e};
        };
    };

    static async updateReview(reviewId,user,review){
        try{
            const updateResponse=await review.updateOne({_id:ObjectID(reviewId)}, 
            {$set:{user:user,review:review}});
            return updateResponse;
        }catch(e){
            console.error(`Unable to update review: ${e}`);
            return{error:e};
        };

    };

    static async getReviewByMovieId(movieId){
        try{
            const cursor=await reviews.find({movieId: parseInt(movieId)});
            return cursor.toArray();
           
        }catch(e){
            console.error(`Unable to get review: ${e}`);
            return{error:e};
        };
    };

};
```

**reviews.route.js**:

```
import express from 'express';
import ReviewsCtrl from "./reviews.controller.js";

const router=express.Router();

router.route("/movie/:id").get(ReviewsCtrl.apiGetReviews);
router.route("/new").post(ReviewsCtrl.apiPostReview);
router.route("/:id")
    .get(ReviewsCtrl.apiGetReviews)
    .put(ReviewsCtrl.apiUpdateReview)
    .delete(ReviewsCtrl.apiDeleteReview)

export default router;
```

**moviedb.js**:

```
import app from './server.js';
import ReviewsDAO from "./dao/reviewsDAO.js";
import mongodb from 'mongodb';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

const MongoClient=mongodb.MongoClient


dotenv.config();
const mongo_username = process.env.MONGO_USERNAME;
const mongo_password = process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD;

const port=4444;

MongoClient.connect(`mongodb+srv://${mongo_username}:${mongo_password}@cluster0.b5f7prn.mongodb.net/test`,
{
  maxPoolSize: 50,
  wtimeoutMS: 2500,
  useNewUrlParser: true
})
.catch(err => {
    console.error(err.stack)
    console.error("Error connecting to the database:", err.message)
    process.exit(1)
  })
.then(async client => {
    await ReviewsDAO.injectDB(client)
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`listening on port ${port}`)
    })
  })
```

Comment: you never called `injectDB` anywhere in the posted code, that's why `reviews` property is `undefined`

Comment: i have called reviewsDAO in the db file like this : .then(async client => {
    await reviewsDAO.injectDB(client)
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`listening on port ${port}`)
    })
  })